# connecting to database from Phalcon takes too long

Tags: mysql, model, database-connection, phalcon

this is a little weird but when I want to access to a model in phalcon it takes about 21 Secs to creating connection but when I want to connect to Database with PDO by same configurations it will connects too fast!
did any body have the same problem before?

I use this configuration for connecting DB

```
return new \Phalcon\Config(array(
  'database' => array(
    'adapter'  => 'Mysql',
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'     => 'testdb',
)
));
```

Comment: Connection time sounds like it is an environment issue and the connection/drive was sleeping. Can you give more details about your environment?

Comment: @david.duncan if that was the case wouldn't using PDO have the same problem?

Comment: Phalcon itself uses PDO to connect to the db, so if connecting directly through PDO doesn't cause the issue,  then the issue is upstream of the PDO call from Phalcon. How many queries are you executing for this particular request? Are you loading the Phalcon db adapter as a shared service? If not, each query you make will load a new adapter, make a new connection, and will make the request very slow.

Comment: Hey, I am also facing similar problem in my phalon project. Did you find any solutions of this problem ?
Can you please help ?